# Nginx: you should increase server_names_hash_bucket_size: 32 - did this but no effect

Tags: nginx

When I run 
    **nginx -t**

I get error

nginx: [emerg] could not build the server_names_hash, you should increase server_names_hash_bucket_size: 32

Then I go and update nginx.conf file, line server_names_hash_bucket_size to 32.

Then I run 
    **service nginx reload**

Then run again **nginx -t** and I am getting the same error.

Why it does not take effect and how could I fix this?

Comment: Looks like setting to 64 does not throw this error anymore. Maybe it was showing current value - 32 which was not enough

Comment: Answer your own question and mark the answer with the green check. This way it will not be an 'unanswered question'

Comment: Too bad I can accept it in 2 days only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting to 64 does not throw this error anymore. Probably it was showing current value - 32 which was not enough.

Comment: server_names_hash_bucket_size 64; is commented in configuration , this let me think that it is default, what is not the case, it should be uncommented ( on raspberry raspbian stretch ). and this fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

In nginx 1.14, there is no default settings in **nginx.conf**, so add the `server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;` into **http**

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
```

Answer (score 1):

Incase someone uncommented the line but it still doesn't work, increase the value by 32 to make it 92. So you should have

`server_names_hash_bucket_size 96;`

Comment: from docs http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html
In this case, the directive value should be increased to the next power of two:

http {
    server_names_hash_bucket_size  64;
    ...
So next is 128, where you got 96?

Answer (score 1):

nginx settings nginx.conf

```
server_names_hash_bucket_size 1024; // or 96
```

Comment: Please add supporting details to your answer.